# Destroy Action Acting Unusual

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The application has: Clients, which has and belongs to many ActionItems, which has and belongs to many Clients. A user, chooses a client (a client they have as a customer), and adds action items (to do's) to that client. -- Like: User creates => "Email client about X topic," for client: Crayola LLC.

I've been instructed to nest resources like so, in routes:

```
resources :clients do
resources :action_items
end
```

So that I can get a URL like:

```
-http://localhost:3000/clients/42/action_items/11
```

To display the action items for a specific client.

However - deleting action items for that client, doesn't work. It's been trying to redirect me to the destroy action, on which I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `clients_action_items' for #    <ActionItemsController:0x007febd0edf800>
```

Prior to this, the delete link, which uses the destroy action, was attempting to redirect me to the show page, on which I was getting:

```
No route matches [POST] "/clients/42/action_items/1"
```

Then I added: post '/clients/:client_id/action_items/:id' => 'action_items#destroy' to the routes file. (and now I get the undefined local variable or method clients_action_items' error.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


get 'users/index'

  get 'users/new'

  get 'users/edit'

  get 'users/delete'

  get 'users/create'

  patch 'users/create'

  patch 'users/update'

  get 'clients/index'

  get 'clients/new'

  get 'clients/edit'

  get 'clients/delete' => 'clients#delete'

  get 'clients/create'

  patch 'clients/create'

  patch 'clients/update'


 post '/clients/:client_id/action_items/:id' => 'action_items#destroy'



  get 'login', :to => "access#index"

    resources :action_items

  #/clients/13/action_items

  resources :clients do
    resources :action_items
  end

  #get 'home/index'

  #get 'home/edit'
#
  #get 'home/delete'

  #get 'home/show'

root 'home#index'

#define, below **, is the URL we named categories/index. It is now localhost:3000/define


  #get 'index' => 'questions#index'

  #get 'questions/edit'

  #get 'new' => 'questions#new'

  #get 'questions/delete'

  #post 'questions/destroy'

  #get 'questions/show'

  #post 'create' => 'questions#create'



  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]

  #   end
end
```

Action Items Controller:

```
class ActionItemsController < ApplicationController

 # before_action :get_owner

    def index
        @action_items = ActionItem.all 
        @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])

    end 

    def new
        @action_items = ActionItem.new
        # @action_items_client = @client.action_items.new 
        @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    end

    def create
            # @action_item = ActionItem.new(action_items_params)
   #        if @action_item.save
   #                redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id)
   #                #renders client individual page
   #        else 
   #                redirect_to(:action => 'new')
    #       end
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])

            @action_item_client = @client.action_items.new(action_items_params)
            if @action_item_client.save
                redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @action_item_client.id, :client_id => @client.id)
            else 
                redirect_to(:action => 'new')
            end
    end

    def edit
        @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
        if @action_item.update_attributes(action_items_params)
            redirect_to(:controller => 'action_items', :action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id)
            flash[:notice] = "Updated"
            else 
                render 'new'

        end 
    end


    def show
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])  
        @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:action_item_id])


    end

    def action_clients
        @action_clients = ActionItem.Client.new 
    end



    def delete
        @action_item = @client.action_items.find(params[:client_id])
    end

    def destroy
        # @action_items = @client.action_items.find(params[:id]).destroy
        # redirect_to(:controller => 'action_items', :action => 'index')

        item = clients_action_items.find(params[:client_id])
        item.destroy
        if params[:client_id]
            redirect_to clients_action_items_path(params[:client_id])
        else 
            redirect_to clients_action_items_path
        end 
    end

    private 
    def action_items_params
        params.require(:action_item).permit(:purpose, :correspondence_method, :know_person, :contact_name_answer, :additional_notes)
    end

    # private
    # def get_owner
    #   if params[:client_id].present?
    #       @owner = user.clients.find(params[:client_id])
    #   else
    #       @owner = user
    #   end 
    # end
  end
```

Index view from which I am deleting an action item:

```
<%= link_to('New Action Item', :controller => 'action_items', :action => 'new') %></br>

<ol><% @action_items.each do |list| %>

<li>

Action Item for <%= @client.name %> is: <strong><%= list.correspondence_method %></strong> Client, about:

<strong><%= list.purpose %> </strong></li>

And you created some additional notes: <strong><%= list.additional_notes %></strong></br></br>  



-- Crud Actions -- </br>

<%= link_to('New Action Item', :controller => 'action_items', :action => 'new') %></br>
<%= link_to('Edit Action Item', :controller => 'action_items', :action => 'edit', :id => list.id) %></br>
<%= link_to('Show Individual', :controller => 'action_items', :action => 'show', :id => list.id) %></br>
<%= button_to('Delete Action Item', :controller => 'action_items', :action => 'destroy', :id => list.id) %></br> 

<h2> new delete </h2> 

</br></br>

<% end %></ol>
```

I have created the foreign key columns in a migration file with a join table called: action_items_clients:

```
class CreateActionItemsClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :action_items_clients, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :action_item_id 
        t.integer :client_id
    end
  end
end
```

-New to rails. Please excuse dirty code. What is wrong here? Why the destroy link issues? Why was the destroy link redirecting to show before, and giving me both routing and ID errors?

Thanks for your time. 
*** EDIT ****

Rake routes output:

```
               Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
            users_index GET      /users/index(.:format)                              users#index
              users_new GET      /users/new(.:format)                                users#new
             users_edit GET      /users/edit(.:format)                               users#edit
           users_delete GET      /users/delete(.:format)                             users#delete
           users_create GET      /users/create(.:format)                             users#create
                        PATCH    /users/create(.:format)                             users#create
           users_update PATCH    /users/update(.:format)                             users#update
          clients_index GET      /clients/index(.:format)                            clients#index
            clients_new GET      /clients/new(.:format)                              clients#new
           clients_edit GET      /clients/edit(.:format)                             clients#edit
         clients_delete GET      /clients/delete(.:format)                           clients#delete
         clients_create GET      /clients/create(.:format)                           clients#create
                        PATCH    /clients/create(.:format)                           clients#create
         clients_update PATCH    /clients/update(.:format)                           clients#update
                        DELETE   /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id(.:format)      action_items#destroy
                  login GET      /login(.:format)                                    access#index
           action_items GET      /action_items(.:format)                             action_items#index
                        POST     /action_items(.:format)                             action_items#create
        new_action_item GET      /action_items/new(.:format)                         action_items#new
       edit_action_item GET      /action_items/:id/edit(.:format)                    action_items#edit
            action_item GET      /action_items/:id(.:format)                         action_items#show
                        PATCH    /action_items/:id(.:format)                         action_items#update
                        PUT      /action_items/:id(.:format)                         action_items#update
                        DELETE   /action_items/:id(.:format)                         action_items#destroy
    client_action_items GET      /clients/:client_id/action_items(.:format)          action_items#index
                        POST     /clients/:client_id/action_items(.:format)          action_items#create
 new_client_action_item GET      /clients/:client_id/action_items/new(.:format)      action_items#new
edit_client_action_item GET      /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id/edit(.:format) action_items#edit
     client_action_item GET      /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id(.:format)      action_items#show
                        PATCH    /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id(.:format)      action_items#update
                        PUT      /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id(.:format)      action_items#update
                        DELETE   /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id(.:format)      action_items#destroy
                clients GET      /clients(.:format)                                  clients#index
                        POST     /clients(.:format)                                  clients#create
             new_client GET      /clients/new(.:format)                              clients#new
            edit_client GET      /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                         clients#edit
                 client GET      /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#show
                        PATCH    /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#update
                        PUT      /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#update
                        DELETE   /clients/:id(.:format)                              clients#destroy
                   root GET      /                                                   home#index
                        GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)              :controller#:action
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to destroy an object using a POST request.

```
No route matches [POST] "/clients/42/action_items/1"
```

Did you try a DELETE request?

```
delete '/clients/:client_id/action_items/:id' => 'action_items#destroy'
```

You can read further about CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Also, can you run rake:routes and post the output here? That will help figure out what routes are actually being generated.

***EDIT***
So, as you can see from the output of rake:routes there is a LOT of duplication. You basically have three models, User, Client and ActionItems with basic CRUD and one login.

Rake file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'login', :to => "access#index"
  resources :users
  resources :action_items
  resources :clients do
    member do
      get :action_items
    end
  end
  root 'home#index'
end
```

Client and ActionItems have a many-to-many relation. If it was a one-to-many ie many ActionItems belong to only one Client then it would have been better to nest the resources.

To show all action items of a client you only need one extra method in client controller.

Clients Controller:

```
def show
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])  
end

def action_items
  @list_action_items = @client.action_items
end
```

Action Items Controller:

```
#Will list all action_items irrespective of which clients they belong to
def index
  @action_items = ActionItem.all  
end 

#For creating a new action item, 
def new
  @action_item = ActionItem.new
  #You can render a form with dropdown here with Client.all to assign the new action_item to a client
end

def create
  @action_item = ActionItem.new(action_items_params)
  if @action_item.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id)
    #renders client individual page
  else 
    redirect_to(:action => 'new')
  end
end

def edit
  @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  if @action_item.update_attributes(action_items_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Updated"
    redirect_to(:controller => 'action_items', :action => 'show', :id => @action_item.id)
  else 
    render 'new'
  end 
end


def show
  @action_item = ActionItem.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  @action_item.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Action Item has been deleted."
  redirect_to action_items_path
end
```

I have tried to simplify the structure here. If you want to perform tasks like deleting all action items of a client from the index/list page of all clients, you can define a method destroy_many in the ActionItems controller which takes client_id as argument, queries all action items and deletes them. 
You don't need separate ClientActionItem controller/routes.
Also, if you want to continue with nested routes,
try

```
<%= button_to('Delete Action Item', client_action_item_path(@client.id, list.id), method: :delete) %></br>
```

The nested route requires two arguments. The first is client.id and second the action_item id.

Comment: I've tried the delete request - and got a different error.  This one: No route matches [POST] "/clients/42/action_items/1"

Rake routes output above, in edited version of post!

Comment: Understood. Thanks for being so concise :) I appreciate your help -   @shifaKhan.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but un-tested. I am not sure of your intentions, but I would use a link_to with a class of button personally.

```
<%= button_to('Delete Action Item', client_action_item_path(@client, list), method: :delete) %></br>
```

Comment: This: client_action_item << is referring to what path? What URL does that translate to? Your line above, created this error: undefined method `client_action_item' for #<#<Class:0x007fcdf1bdeb30>:0x007fcdf1f44e00> -- Thanks for your response! What do you think?

Comment: It should be client_action_item_path(list.id), sorry. I will update my answer.

Comment: Basically that will realise the named route "client_action_item" with the request method delete, which from your rake routes is: DELETE   /clients/:client_id/action_items/:id(.:format)      action_items#destroy.

Comment: Ok - understood. That worked. It's weird how Delete action stopped working correctly, and method: :delete is what I had to do, with button_to instead of link_to. I read it has something to do w/ JQuery. Couldn't figure that out. Thanks for your time !! Really appreciate it.